# Bash script for renew Logfile per day

Tags: bash, logging

I have bash script running as service where the logfile not renew per day.
The log filename remains as the date the script started (Start_Process.sh)

Example: I ran this (Start_Process.sh) on 1-Aug-2023.
today 22-Aug-2023 the log filename still `process_2023_08_1.log`

In my start script (Start_Process.sh) have this line for execute this script (Process.sh)

Start_Process.sh script

```
/usr/bin/nohup ./Process.sh >> process_`date "+%Y_%m_%d"`.log /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Process.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
(
..
...
...

) 2>&1 | tee process_`date "+%Y_%m_%d"`.log
```

The reason I'm put this at the end of script

```
2>&1 | tee process_`date "+%Y_%m_%d"`.log
```

to have detail log (each line in the script).

Expectation: logfile having all output each line in the script.
Renew per day example process_2023_08_1.log, process_2023_08_2.log n etc

how to have logfile per day?

Comment: The mainstream way to handle that on Linux is to write your logs to a fixed filename, then having an other process "rotate" this file

Comment: Thanks a lot get the idea already will use Logrotate function

Comment: Sorry to say, but your code is virtually unreadable due to poor formatting. Please [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Why not just let `systemd-journald` manage log storage automatically for the service? It will work way better than any “wheel reinventions” in Bash ever could. `journalctl`’s command line options `-S` and `-U` make it easy to inspect logs from a specified time interval (e.g. a day).